# Python: puts the seconds to zero in a milliseconds number

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

My code looks like this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.local
collection = db.orderbook_update
orderbook = collection.find({}).sort('lastUpdated', pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(1)
for order in orderbook:
    print(order['lastUpdated'])
```

And my output like this: `1538589898191.0`
What I would like to do is put the seconds of this output to zero, I have no idea how to do it... any help? Thanks!

Comment: What are "the seconds" of `1538589898191.0 `? Is that a time stamp?

Comment: It is a unix timestamp indeed in milliseconds

Comment: You mean you want to display the duration from "last updated" to "now" as something like days, hours, minutes?

Comment: No, just take the lastUpdated value (1538589898191.0 ) and put the seconds to zero

Comment: BTW, the first `client = MongoClient()` is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to just integer-divide `//` by `60000` to get rid of both milliseconds and seconds, then multiply by `60` again to get a timestamp of seconds, or by `60000` to get a timestamp of milliseconds.

```
>>> t = 1538589898191.0 
>>> import time
>>> time.gmtime(t//1000)
>>> time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=3, tm_hour=18, tm_min=4, tm_sec=58, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=276, tm_isdst=0)
>>> time.gmtime(t//60000*60)
>>> time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=3, tm_hour=18, tm_min=4, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=276, tm_isdst=0)
>>> t // 60000 * 60000
1538589840000.0
```